# li with longer text, background width issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle with Issue](http://jsfiddle.net/gvxx4/8/)

It can be observable in the screen short below, `li` with longer text has bigger background while other `li` background remained shorter. 
Note: `<ul>` is scrollable. I have tried many CSS properties but not able to fix the issue.

**Note:** Giving background to `<ul>` is not required. I need to give background to individual `li` items.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `white-space:nowrap` and make his container in this case the `ul` fill the space of the longest item then you need to change the `block` behavior. Try this:

```
ul {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gvxx4/13/)**